# Circular biscuits in a circular pan.

Tags: soft-question, packing-problem

This question comes from a discussion with my wife about the more efficient way for cooking biscuits.
Here the problem:

We have a circular pan with a diameter of $30 cm$ and we have two round stamps for biscuits with diameters of $5$ and $3$ cm and we want produce a number $n$ of biscuits in a proportion that is about $1/3$ of $5 cm$ biscuits and $2/3$ of $3 cm$.
What is the more efficient way to put the biscuits on the pan?

My wife say that usually she cooks separately the two measures, but I say that it's better to mix the two in a way the better use the space. So she asked to me what is this better way. But, after a bit of thinking, I've not a good answer.

I know that the circles packing is a difficult problem, with a lot of literature produced about it, but my knowledge about it is very poor.  I've seen the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle) where are listed some optimal configurations, but all with the little circle with the same diameter.

So I ask if there is some way to solve the problem that is not by trial and error.

( sorry for my bad english).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407145v2) would be of interest. It's about compactly packing two different sized circles in the plane.

Comment: Thank you. I'll read it. It seems a generalization of my problem to the optimization of the diameter of the little biscuit, but the circular pan is a problem. I will buy a rectangular pan :)

Comment: I think the paper doesn't consider boundaries at all. It just talks about an infinite plane. However, some of the tilings they recommend in the paper for a ratio of ~ $0.6 = \frac{3}{5}$ could probably still serve you reasonably well.

Comment: I too have struggled to tile cookies in a pan. And mine was rectangular. Go figure.